# Campy N3W freehub body

Tags: compatibility, freehub, campagnolo

I have a pretty good idea that Campagnolo's new freehub body standard they term "N3W" is only compatible with Campy cassettes 10-13 speed. It can also fit 9, 10 & 11 tooth small cogs. Looking at Campy's website that introduces this technology (and a brief review of other websites that discuss N3W), it's not clear to me if there is cross compatibility with Shimano HG cassettes.  Can anyone confirm that Campy's N3W system is only compatible with their cassettes?

Comment: N3W is not only for 10-12 speed, but also for 13 speed (Ekar). In fact, it was specifically introduced to make Ekar and its 9T sprocket possible.

Comment: @Erikoenig edited the question to include 13 speed in the range. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Google the spline patterns for Campagnolo and Shimano freehubs, you can see that they are very different. Thus, there’s no way to get a Shimano cassette onto a Campy freehub body.

That said, Campy do make Shimano freehub bodies available for, as far as I know, all their wheels (and Fulcrum’s wheels, as Fulcrum is a subsidiary of Campagnolo).

Additionally, it’s widely known that you could put a Campagnolo 11S cassette into a Shimano drivetrain, and it would shift fine. There isn’t enough room for the cog-cog distance to be different by enough to throw the shifting off. The same has got to be true of 12s.

Comment: Doesn't one entire speed group (10 I'm thinking) where Campy uses a variable cable pull at the shifter requiring the cassette spacing to be different between cogs, cause misshifts past the point of tolerable?

Comment: Good idea for a search querey.  In the accompanying photos, the one I most paid attention to was a close up of the body and a wide spline was up. It's what set me off trying to find clarity regarding N3W's multi-compatability.

Comment: @Jeff I believe that all their groups use variable cable pull. The thing is with 11s, the variation in cog spacing works out to be not an issue with a Shimano system - I’ve used a Campy compatible cassette in a Shimano system before and I can attest to this.